# Legend disappears when moved inside of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot that shows the home range size of several animals over time. The legend automatically populates to the right of the plot, and I can successfully move it above, below, or to the left of the plot with `+ theme(legend.position= "position")`, but when I try to move the legend within the plot using `+ theme(legend.position= c(1, 250))` it disappears.

My data consists of columns "id" (a character vector), "wtd_area" (numeric), and "study_year" (numeric).

```
data %>%
ggplot(aes(x= study_year, y= wtd_area, color= id, shape= id)) + 
  theme_js() + 
  geom_point(size= 3) + geom_line(aes(group=id), size= 1) + 
  ylim(0,160) + scale_color_manual(values= palette) + 
  labs(x= NULL, y= NULL, color= "Animal ID", shape= "Animal ID") +
  theme(legend.position= c(1,150))
```

I have:

1.) Confirmed that the custom theme `theme_js()` is not interfering by switching to a generic theme.

2.) Added `aes(color= id, shape= id)` and `aes(color= id)` to `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` respectively.

3.) Added `show.legend= TRUE` to `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`.

4.) Added `aesthetics= "color"` to `scale_color_manual()`.

`palette` is a character vector containing color hex codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position should be on a scale of 0 to 1, rather than corresponding to your axes. The x,y is 0,0 (bottom left) to 1,1 (top right). Here, I use the `ToothGrowth` sample data as an example.

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=dose)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2))
```

[image]